# Como arreglar Command + R en Virtual Box?

Tags: windows, virtualbox

estoy usando Virtual Box corriendo Windows 7 en una `iMac 10.11.6` y estoy intentando de abrir "RUN" con Command + R pero cada vez que le pasaba Command + R al teclado la VM se apagaba y prendía, eso lo arregle cuando fui a `INPUT > Keyboard Settings >` y borre el comando que estaba apagando la computadora cada vez que escribía Command + R. Ahora no hace nada pero quiero saber puedo abrir RUN haciendo `Command + R`, `CTRL + Z or C` funciona bien. Cualquier tipo de ayuda sera apreciada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo lo solucioné asignando al Comando Ejecutar un Atajo, pero dentro del Sistema Operativo, de la siguiente manera:

1. Primero reasignamos la **Tecla Host o 'Anfitrión'** a una tecla **diferente** que CTRL Derecho, puede ser cualquiera menos ALT y CTRL.
2. En Buscar escribimos '**Ejecutar**'
3. Click Derecho y del menú emergente seleccionamos '**Abrir Ubicación del archivo**'.
4. Una vez abierta la ubicación del archivo, hacemos click derecho y elegimos **Propiedades**.
5. **Le asignas una Letra por defecto**. Los atajos usan **CTRL** + **ALT** + (ESCOGER TECLA)